# date() is showing December 1969

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY `news_id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$date = $row['time_posted'];
echo "<i> " .date("Y/m/d", $date) . "</i>: ";
```

I used timestamp in mysql.

Comment: What's the field type of `time_posted`? Did you even check its value before throwing it in the `date` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
```

[TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) columns are not displayed as unix timestamps (anymore).

> TIMESTAMP columns are displayed in the
>   same format as DATETIME columns. In
>   other words, the display width is
>   fixed at 19 characters, and the format
>   is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: In other words, to expand. You've retrieved "2010-04-25 19:36:05" from MySQL and passed that directly to PHP. `date()` is expecting a numeric value, so the string's invalid and treated as NULL, which gets cast to 0, which is converted into the epoch, and adjusted for your timezone. You're somewhere WEST of Greenwich, so your local time at time '0' was in 1969 somewhere.

Comment: @Marc - a real Rube Goldberg chain of events.  Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX epoch was at January 1, 1970 at exactly midnight UTC. If you live in a timezone behind UTC, timestamp 0 will show up sometime in the evening of December 31, 1969. (`$date` is most likely 0)

Comment: `date()` warns if you give it a non-numeric variable.

Comment: `date()` _notices_ when you give it a non-numeric variable and assumes 0. Most setups (unfortunately) ignore notices.